# Removing dynamically created elements with vanilla JavaScript by clicking on them

Tags: javascript, dom

I wrote the code below to dynamically add li elements to a ul element. I want the user to be able to click on any one of them and have that li item removed. I know how to do this with JQuery but I want to know how to do it with vanilla JavaScript.I understand that removeChild() is the only method at my dispose to do this but I am a bit confused as to how to use it to accomplish the task at hand.

Thank you.

http://jsfiddle.net/3wk0866o/

---

**HTML**

```
<form id="input-form">
    <input id="input-field" type = "text"/>
<button>Submit</button>
</form>

<ul id="list" >

</ul>
```

---

**JavaScript**

```
var form = document.getElementById("input-form");



function getInput(event){
    event.preventDefault();     
    var inputValue = document.getElementById("input-field").value  

    form.reset();              

    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += "<li>"+ inputValue +"</li>"; 
}
form.addEventListener("submit",getInput,false)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

http://jsfiddle.net/3wk0866o/1/

**I just added this listener function:**

```
function removeItem(e) {
    var target = e.target;
    if(target.tagName !== 'LI') return;
    target.parentNode.removeChild(target);
}
list.addEventListener('click', removeItem);
```

It adds an event listener to the "list" `UL` element, and listens for clicks inside of it. `e.target` is the element clicked, and if the element clicked isn't a `LI` element, then the function just `returns`. If it is, then it removes the element and all of its children.

**If you want to know how the last bit that removes the element works:**

`target.parentNode` finds the parent element of the clicked `LI` element (`UL`), and then  you just simply call `removeChild` on that node, since `LI` is a child element of `UL`. You can also use the [remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) method on the element directly, but that is not well supported yet.

---

**Note that you might run into problems if your `LI` element has children**; in that case, the target might show up as one of `LI`'s children and not as `LI`. To solve that you can use a loop that walks through the DOM until it gets to an `UL` element, or until it finds a `LI` element to remove:

http://jsfiddle.net/3wk0866o/3/

```
function removeItem(e) {
    var target = e.target;
    while(target.tagName !== 'UL') {
        if(target.tagName === 'LI') {
            return target.parentNode.removeChild(target);
        }
        target = target.parentNode;
    }
}
list.addEventListener('click', removeItem);
```

---

If your `LI` elements will only have text inside of them, then the first solution is enough.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an `onclick` event listener directly to the new child.

```
function getInput(event){
    event.preventDefault();     
    var inputValue = document.getElementById("input-field").value  

    console.log(inputValue)
    form.reset();              // _______________Reset method 

    // Create new element.
    var new_li = document.createElement('li');
    new_li.innerHTML = inputValue;
    // When it is clicked, remove it.
    new_li.onclick = function() {
        this.remove();
    };

    // Append element as child to list.
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(new_li);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3wk0866o/2/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use parent.removeChild(child) to remove the item but you might have problem with finding the child because the item has been added on the fly.

2 suggestion:

1. add the item in the list as you add them to the list and then grab them from   the list instead of finding them on the page.
2. use .On function to attach click event and then use this in the event to grab   them.